# How to redirect PWA to new server after being opened?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, raspberry-pi, progressive-web-apps

this is my first post here.
I'm working on a group school project and made a PWA which is hosted on an external Cloudflare server with a certificate. For the duration of testing, the PWA sent data to that server through NodeJS. Now, after installing the PWA on a mobile device, I would like it to communicate with another server instead, a Raspberry PI with a fixed IP acting as a Wifi hotspot in order for the PWA to send data in the database it's hosting, and effectively only keep the original server as the server that permits downloading and installing the PWA on devices.

Now my issue is, when I change the NodeJS code in the PWA to indicate which server it's supposed to establish a connection with, the PWA still communicates with the server hosting it instead of contacting the new server. I tried changing the ip address and port in the PWA's NodeJS code to indicate the new server it's supposed to send data to, but when testing, it still sends its data to the host server instead of establishing a new connection to the rpi server.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome. Thing is, you are doing your best to sort-of describe your situation, but there's no code, no minimal examples. What you describe here will make sense in your head, but there are so many components here that it will be hard to help you any further. Because with PWAs, they're usually installed from a certain server, and making a NodeJS server forward connections will not really help you? There is too little here to help you. So maybe clear your mind a bit, focus and try to make your question understandable to someone who knows _nothing_ about your project. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I'll take a moment to add more examples of what's happening. Cheers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.